# How to connect between two Linux machines VIA Linux router machine

Tags: linux, route

I have three Linux machines that connected as the following:

```
   Linux_machine1  -->  Route_linux_machine -->  Linux_machine2
```

How to ssh from Linux_machine1   to Linux_machine2 Only VIA Route_linux_machine

Like Route_linux_machine is route get-way to Linux_machine2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the `Route_linux_machine` is.

### `Route_linux_machine` is a router

If it's only a router (means, no SSH service/account there): then you should add some `iptables` rules to redirect network traffic. For instance, something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d linux_machine2_alias \
    -p TCP --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination linux_machine2:22
```

(where `linux_machine2_alias` is another IP address, owned by `route_linux_machine`)
Then, from your machine, you have to SSH to `linux_machine2_alias` (which actually is the router) who will redirect it to `linux_machine2`.

### `Route_linux_machine` is a SSH gateway

If you have a SSH account on `Route_linux_machine`, then you can make an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh user@route_linux_machine -L2222:linux_machine2:22
```

Then, the 2222 port of your own machine will be redirected to the port 22 of `linux_machine2` via `route_linux_machine`. You'd just have to do:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 2222
```

While it looks like you're connecting to your own machine (`localhost`), you will actually be redirected to `linux_machine2`.

As an alternative, if you don't want to use tunnel, you can use nested `ssh` commands:

```
ssh -t -A user@route_linux_machine ssh user@linux_machine2
```

It will prompt you first for `route_linux_machine` password, then `linux_machine2` password.